# how to set the selected value of dropdownlist in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-helper

i am using htmlhelper dropdownlist with Razor and setting it,s value by jquery. it not working.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Gendar", new List<SelectListItem> {
    new SelectListItem { Text="Are You Male or Female", Value="Are You Male or Female" },
    new SelectListItem { Text="Male", Value="male" },
    new SelectListItem { Text="Female", Value="female" }
}, new { @class = "form-control" }


<script>
    ($(this).attr("data-Gendar") == "Male" ? $("#Gendar[value='male']").prop("selected", true) : $("#Gendar[value ='female']").prop("selected", true));
</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is not working.

Comment: What are you attempting to do here? You script makes no sense at all. `$(this)` is referring to the `Window` object! It does not have an attribute named `data-Gendar` and neither does the dropdownlist your generating. Your first option makes no sense, but to initially set the selected option set the value of property `Gendar` to either "Male" or "Female" in the GET method before you pass the model to the view

Comment: And if you want to set it using javascript, explain what event you want to trigger the change (and inside that event handler, use `$('#Gendar').val('male');` or `$('#Gendar').val('female');`

Answer (score 0):

```
    set on change event, like: 
     @Html.DropDownList("Gendar", new List<SelectListItem>
                                {
                                new SelectListItem { Text="Are You Male or Female", Value="Are You Male or Female" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text="Male", Value="male" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text="Female", Value="female" }
                                }, new { onchange = "onChange(this)" })

//js
<script>
    function onChange(e)   {
        (e.value == "male" ? $("#Gendar[value='male']").prop("selected", true) : $("#Gendar[value ='female']").prop("selected", true));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: have you loaded jQuery library?

Comment: i copied prop("selected", "selected") replace it with my prop("selected", true) but still the result is same...its not working

Comment: Can you check in developer tools to see if you have some js errors? F12 normally for any browser?

Comment: yes i checked it in inspect element console windows with the help of $.fn.jquery
my jquery version is "2.1.1"

Comment: <script>
    $("#Gendar option[value='male']").prop("selected", "selected");
</script>

Comment: You should have selected male in your ddl

Comment: i  write my code with same configuration as i mention the code in my question

Comment: Can you out here you code? I do not understand what is :$(this).attr("data-DonarNeedy") == "Donar"?  -

Comment: Okay, I got now your issue, so you need to add onchange event for ddl: @Html.DropDownList("Gendar", new List<SelectListItem>
                            {
                            new SelectListItem { Text="Are You Male or Female", Value="Are You Male or Female" },
                            new SelectListItem { Text="Male", Value="male" },
                            new SelectListItem { Text="Female", Value="female" }
                            }, new { onchange = "onChange(this)" })

Comment: <script>
    function onChange(e)   {
        (e.value == "male" ? $("#Gendar[value='male']").prop("selected", true) : $("#Gendar[value ='female']").prop("selected", true));
    }
</script> - I will edit my answer

Comment: would you explain your question ...?

Comment: any luck based on example?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code need to bed executed when document is ready and the page is fully loaded

try this

```
<script>
(function() {
    ($(this).attr("data-Gendar") === "Male" ? $("#Gendar[value='male']").prop("selected", true) : $("#Gendar[value ='female']").prop("selected", true));
}());
```